# How to set Persian calendar,currency,numbers,date and time and text in oracle database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have installed oracle database 12c on my laptop.

I want to be able to store text,numbers,calendar,currency,... in my local language (Persian) in database tables and also show contents in Persian when retrieving data from tables.

I'm also using APEX 5 that I want these capabilities in there too?

Is it possible? Does Oracle support these in both database 12c and APEX 5?
How can I set these settings and where?

I'm using Windows 8.1 enterprise x64.

Answer (score 2):

The magic key word is `NLS` (National Language Support). It will define the dateformat, calender format etc.

You can query your current `NLS`-settings with this command:

```
SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters;
```

If you want to change it in a session or an instance you can query the current settings using this views:

```
SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters;
-- or
SELECT * FROM nls_instance_parameters;
```

You need to set this `NLS` settings, maybe the proper `ISO` as character set too.

```
NLS_LANG=ARABIC_SAUDI ARABIA.UTF8
NLS_LANGUAGE=PERSIAN
NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN
```

You have some possible solutions to setting the `NLS`. If you want to use it globally I would suggest to set it in the initialization parameters.

You can read more about setting the [NLS in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/server.816/a76966/ch2.htm).

Oracle 12c should support persian, as stated in this [whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/globalization12c-datasheet-1968798.pdf) in the section "New Locale Coverage".

By the way, if you need a larger multi language support, you may want to use AL32UTF8 instead of normal UTF8 language sets. You can read something about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch6unicode.htm) and [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3514820).

Comment: thanks.yes I want  to set these permanently. How can I set the initialization parameters for this?

Comment: how to set those three lines you said,I mean what is the syntax?

Comment: Should I use NVARCHAR2 instead of VARCHAR2 for inserting persian?

Comment: You have a `INIT.ORA` in your installation. You can define those settings there and restart the service. Nvarchar is always better for multilanguage support as it supports the UTF characters.

Comment: @Ionic - why NLS_LANG=ARABIC_SAUDI ARABIA.UTF8 - it was my understanding that the Persian alphabet differs signficantly from the "classic" Arabic one (although, obviously, they are both forms of the Arabic script).

Comment: @Vérace I wasn't sure if this collation would be good enough for persian. I haven't found the correct collation for persion, just the mention that Oracle supports it. This is the bad and the good news together. I found information that it would be possible with the Arabia. The official docs from Oracle are not really clear at this point.

Answer (score -1):

You can go to the registry (considering you have a windows machine) can update the nls_lang variable to ARABIC_SAUDI ARABIA.UTF8. It should do the work.